# how to use orientation in scroll viewer like scrollbar

Tags: wpf

how to use orientation in scroll viewer like scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but the ScrollViewer has two properties called `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` which you can set to `Auto`, `Hidden`, `Visible` and `Disabled`.

So if you want to show the vertical or horizontal scrollbar of the ScrollViewer you can set one of them to Visible.